# mlr3: obtaining response (predicted survival time) from surv.gbm

Tags: r, survival-analysis, gbm, mlr3

surv.gbm in the mlr3 framework outputs linear predictors, however what I'm really interested in are predicted survival times per case, which I want to compare with the actual survival times. Is there a way to obtain actual survival times?

In the mlr3 book, there is an example of a transformation between linear predictors and a distribution.

```
pod = po("distrcompose", param_vals = list(form = "ph", overwrite = FALSE))
prediction = pod$predict(list(base = prediction_distr, pred = prediction_lp))$output
```

Is there a way to change this pipeline so that it converts "lp" to "response" ?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible it just requires another transformation. Your first step is correct to compose a distribution from a linear predictor; as you're using `surv.gbm` only Cox PH is possible as the underlying model so default for `distrcompose` works for this.

Now you need to use `crankcompose` in order to create a survival time prediction from the distribution, you could use the mean, median, or mode of the distribution, people usually pick mean or median but that's your choice! Just make sure to include `response = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE`. Example code below, includes creating predictions and scoring with RMSE (surprisingly quite good!). I think the book may need updating...

Thanks,
Raphael

```
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(mlr3proba)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3)

learn =  ppl("crankcompositor", ppl("distrcompositor", lrn("surv.gbm")),
             response = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE, method = "mean",
             graph_learner = TRUE)
set.seed(1)
task = tgen("simsurv")$generate(50)
learn$train(task)
p = learn$predict(task)
p$score(msr("surv.rmse"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works! If you plan to update the book, i think the most helpful approach to newbies to this framework would be to include an example of a complete workflow, from task to visualisation, and predicting on a new dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think the survival chapter assumes that people will have read at least the intro chapter. Also there are examples from task to prediction/visualisation, I'm happy to add detail where needed but not sure which parts you think need more examples?

Comment: The bulk of what I'm suggesting is already covered in the chapter, it's like 70% of the complete workflow. What would make it complete would be some way to make plots like the very last plot in this blog: https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/. At the moment autoplot does not seem to work with survival predictions, and you would expect something slightly different than the general output anyway. I only find the results convincing when my predicted survival curve is close to  the actual data (KM curve). But this is turning into a feature request. :-)

Comment: Ah excellent point, we do have plotting features of both prediction error curves and simulated predictions, I also want to add calibration plots. Feel free to up-vote these issues so I don't forget about them: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3proba/issues/155 https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3proba/issues/156

Comment: One last question: is there an internal method to obtain the predicted event status(TRUE/FALSE)? If I understand this correctly, you would need a cutoff value for the crank.  I can generate a cutoff manually, but it needs to be consistent with the ci. So if this is already implemented that would be great.

Comment: No that would be a reduction to binary classification which isn't currently implemented however that is also on the list, the way it would work would be to add another pipeline with a given threshold that will transform 'response' or 'distr' to binary predictions over all times or threshold 'crank'. But I'd be careful with thresholding crank as it's an inherently meaningless quantity... As you've already generated event times makes more sense just to do this over all time-points